# "Pipenv --three" no funciona para crear el entorno virtual

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

¡Hola!

He instalado `Python 3.10`, y a continuación he utilizado el terminal `Git Bash` para instalar `pip`.

`Pip` se ha instalado correctamente, y luego he querido instalar `pipenv`, para lo cual he escrito:

`pip install pipenv`

Esto también ha indicado que está correcto, que no ha habido ningún error y que se ha instalado correctamente.

El problema es que cuando he querido ir a mi proyecto para ejecutar Pipenv, he escrito: `pipenv --three`, y me dice `bash: pipenv: command not found`

He desinstalado e instalado Python de nuevo para poder asegurarme en la instalación que le daba a "Add to PATH", por si acaso. Pero ni así tampoco.

¿Me podrían ayudar? Gracias!

Comment: ¿Lo escribistes así, con mayúsculas "Pipenv"?

Comment: @CandidMoe No, lo escribí en minúscula, así: ``pipenv --three``, solo que se me había quedado en mayúsculas en la pregunta :)